# How to configure a backup certificate pin in Android

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, okhttp

I am currently using this code to have the public key pinning

```
    String pin = "WpuKe****************GO=";
    String pin_backup = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=";
    OkHttpClientFactory okHttpClientFactory = () -> {
        CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                .add(domain, "sha256/" + pin)
                .add(domain, "sha256/" + pin_backup)
                .build();
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
                .cookieJar(new ReactCookieJarContainer())
                .build();
    };
```

I was able to get the current pin by using this [get_pin_from_certificate.py](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit/blob/master/get_pin_from_certificate.py) because I already have the certificate available.

But how would I configure the backup pin? If I am not wrong, backup pin is generated from a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` that is not even created yet.

In fact all I can get from my server side is a `Certificate Signing Request` that they would (hopefully) use to create a new certificate in future.

But I don't see a way to get the pin out of this CSR file. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can only pin existing keys/certificates. A certificate signing request does contain the public key of an already created key. You can also pin the public key of one or more CAs that the server will use now and in the future, but pinning a CA somewhat reduces the effectiveness of pinning. Pinning is not a panacea, it comes with tradeoffs that can't be ignored. It's good that you're considering these trade-offs now.

Comment: 'A certificate signing request does contain the public key of an already created key' - Can I use this to get the SubjectPublicKeyInfo? If so can you please point me on how to achieve that.